# Baking animation for an object with a lattice modifier

Tags: animation, modifiers, baking, lattice

I have a sword with a lattice modifier on it. The sword and the lattice are both parented to an empty that swings the sword. I animated the lattice to deform and stretch the sword in the middle of the arc.

I'm trying to apply the stretching animation to the sword but it seems like the modifier can only be applied to the current frame it's on, and baking the animations for the sword or the lattice doesn't work either as the modifier still has to be applied to the sword after that.

Any ideas on how to make it work? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i recommend using the free AnimAll-add-on. With this you can keyframe vertex location(-changes). By this you can animate your lattice vertices on every frame you like.

Example:

[image]